# Swift 3: No such module 'os.log'

Tags: swift, cocoa

I was trying to compile a swift 3 file which contains nothing but:

```
import Cocoa
```

The compiler output was:

```
<unknown>:0: error: missing required module 'os.log'
```

So I edited the file to be:

```
import os.log
import Cocoa
```

And now the compiler output is:

```
test.swift:1:8: error: no such module 'os.log'
```

I suspect that the compiler is having trouble finding the legitimate module os.log. I should note that I'm editing the file in VIM, and the same program works fine in my Swift playground.

Comment: Are you running the compile command from vim? Otherwise, this probably isn't a vim problem.

Comment: No, I'm running it from the CLI (_swiftc test.swift_). Sorry, didn't mean to suggest it was a Vim problem, I just meant to convey that I'm not using XCode -- I've removed the Vim tag.

Comment: I've made a file with only `import Cocoa` in it and `swiftc test.swift` works without errors. Are you sure about the context of this issue? Which version of OS X are you on?

Comment: I'm on 10.11.6, and the output of 'swift --version' is [Apple Swift version 3.0 (swiftlang-800.0.43.6 clang-800.0.38) Target: x86_64-apple-macosx10.9]

Comment: I'm using the same version. :/

Comment: Having the same after running the swift migration tool

Answer (score 3):

You need this declaration:

```
import os
```

[source](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/61338)